# Is a unit the same thing as an invertible element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is a unit the same thing as an invertible element?

Otherwise, what does a unit mean?

Comment: Yes, *a* unit is simply another name for an invertible element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

Here is the link on wikipedia for unit in ring theory, which is what I assume you mean.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29)